# Always Getting Not Found 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I have following code in my

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Used to connect to the MongoDB database
var mongo = require('mongodb')


var routes = require('./routes/index');

var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();


// Define the directory with the views and to use Jade
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Define what route files to use being routes/index.js for /
// routes/users.js for /users
// The route files then render the page
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
console.log("The Value of Appadadasd",""+ app);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {


  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my **index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');



/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/AddServer';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('users');

    //Create some users
    var user1 = {name: 'modulus admin', age: 42, roles: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user']};
    var user2 = {name: 'modulus user', age: 22, roles: ['user']};
    var user3 = {name: 'modulus super admin', age: 92, roles: ['super-admin', 'admin', 'moderator', 'user']};

    // Insert some users
    collection.insert([user1, user2, user3], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Inserted %d documents into the "users" collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result.length, result);
      }
      //Close connection
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

and my `users.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i type http://localhost:3000/ it working for perfectly 
but when i am trying to call  http://localhost:3000/users its giving me

Not Found

404

```
Error: Not Found
    at D:\AddServer\AddServer\app.js:45:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
    at next (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (D:\AddServer\AddServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

Its not routing to `users.js` I think i am doing some silly mistakes but i am new node not able to figure it out.

Comment: localhost:3000/users searches for a folder in the root of your website called users and loads the index.html if it can find any. you need to specify the file it needs to get with the file extension (.js in this case) also user.js !== users.js

Comment: i miss types user.js and its users.js

Comment: Mukesh Sharma answered to Your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mounting `users` routes at `/users` by defining

```
app.use('/users', users);
```

But, in your `users.js` file, you have defined only `/users` route, which is accessible by `http://localhost:3000/users/users` (because of mounting), not by `http://localhost:3000/users`

Try changing that `path` of the route from `/users` to `/` in `users.js`

e.g.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

**Edit**

After discussing the exact requirement, you can do the following changes to access `http://localhost:3000/user`

**app.js**

```
app.use('/user', users);
```

**users.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh Sharma i want to access on url http://localhost:3000/user what i have to write in app.js and users.js?